# What about $\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\zeta(x)-\frac{1}{x^x-1}\right)=1+\gamma$?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta, online-resources

When I type

> 1 in the box **lim x to**, and
>
> zeta(x)-1/(x^x-1) in the box **Function**,

of this [online calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=7c220a2091c26a7f5e9f1cfb099511e3) (**Wolfram Alpha**) one has as output
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\zeta(x)-\frac{1}{x^x-1}\right)=1+\gamma,$$
where $\zeta(x)$ is the **Riemann zeta function**, and $\gamma$ is the **Euler- Mascheroni constant**.

I know that
$$\lim_{x\to 1^{+}}\left(\zeta(x)-\frac{1}{x-1}\right)=\gamma,$$
and understand the proof.

> **Question.** What about
> $$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\zeta(x)-\frac{1}{x^x-1}\right)=1+\gamma?$$
> Canyou give a proof of previous limit when $x\to 1^{+}$? **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: What about looking at the difference between $1/(x-1)$ and $1/(x^x-1)$. Just Taylor expand around $x=1$, and you will find the extra $1$.

Comment: Thanks @mickep, I will try your hint, but you or other user feel free to provide an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*I do not know if this answers your question; so, please forgive me if I am off-topic.*

Built around $x=1$, we have $$\zeta(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}+\gamma -\gamma _1 (x-1)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ where appears  the Stieltjes constant. On the other hand, starting from $$x^x=1+(x-1)+(x-1)^2+\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^3+O\left((x-1)^4\right) $$ $$\frac{1}{x^x-1}=\frac{1}{x-1}-1+\frac{x-1}{2}+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ So, $$\zeta(x)-\frac{1}{x^x-1}=(1+\gamma )-\left(\gamma _1+\frac{1}{2}\right) (x-1)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ and then the result.

**Edit**

Making the problem more general, it is quite simple to show that $$\zeta(x)-\frac{1}{x^{x^n}-1}=(n+\gamma )- \left(\gamma _1+\frac{n^2}{2}\right)(x-1)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$

Comment: (+1) I think you are on topic, and this is more or less what I was suggesting in my comment.

Comment: @mickep. Thank you and this is exactly what you suggested while I was typing. Cheers.

Comment: I will read your proof with more detail, but I accept your answer, very thanks much @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: @JuanLG. You are very welcome ! What I did matches almost exactly what mickep was suggesting in comments.

Comment: Are your mathematics and your results, **mickep** and **Claude Leibovici**. Thanks

Comment: @JuanLG. What do you mean by *Are your mathematics* ? By the way, did you notice *que somos vecinos, amigo !* ?

Comment: That is your result, I don't know if previous result was know, but it is obvious that you get a proof @ClaudeLeibovici